# Vue select affecting other selector's currently selected choice

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table that displays a certain Nova resource. For each row, I have a selector that would allow me to perform one action from a dropdown. The problem is, let's say I have 3 rows. Each row would have the same selector. Let's say the selector has options A, B, and C. If I go to the first row and select option B, the other selectors also change their currently selected value to B. I'm assuming this is because all of the selectors have the same v-model binding, but I'm not sure how to get around this.

This is the code for the table and the selector:

```js
<table id="favorites">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Source</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Date of Creation</th>
                <th>Posted Status</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
    
            <tr v-for="(favorite, index) in favorites" :key="index">
                <td>{{favorite.id}}</td>
                <td>{{favorite.title}}</td>
                <td>{{favorite.source}}</td>
                <td>{{favorite.description}}</td>
                <td>{{favorite.created_at}}</td>
                <td>
                    <div v-if="favorite.posted_status === 2">
                        <button class="button-posted button4">Posted</button>
                    </div>
                    <div v-else>
                        <button class="button-not-posted button4">Not Posted</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select @change="toggle_posted(favorite)" v-model="selected_state" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                        <option selected disabled>Choose an action </option>    
                        <option v-for="(state, index) in posted_states" :key="index" :value="state.id">{{state.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I want to separate the selectors so that they don't mirror each other. It's also worth noting that while the other selectors change, they don't actually call the `toggle_posted` method. Only the selector I chose does.

Comment: You're binding all the selects to the same `v-model` .. you probably want to use an array for the model as well (e.g. `v-model="selected_state[index]"`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530507

Comment: I knew it was the binding but I didn't know how to go about it. Thank you very much, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A straight-forward way to fix this would be adding a `selected_state` attribute for each list item in `favorites`:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({
    favorites: [
      { id:1, title:'1', source:'1', description:'1', created_at:'1', posted_status: 1, selected_state:null },
      { id:2, title:'2', source:'2', description:'2', created_at:'2', posted_status: 2, selected_state:null }
    ],
    selected_state: null,
    posted_states: [
      { id:1, name:'1' }, { id:2, name:'2' }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    toggle_posted(favorite) {
      console.log(favorite)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table id="favorites">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Source</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Date of Creation</th>
      <th>Posted Status</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(favorite, index) in favorites" :key="index">
      <td>{{favorite.id}}</td>
      <td>{{favorite.title}}</td>
      <td>{{favorite.source}}</td>
      <td>{{favorite.description}}</td>
      <td>{{favorite.created_at}}</td>
      <td>
        <div v-if="favorite.posted_status === 2">
          <button class="button-posted button4">Posted</button>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
          <button class="button-not-posted button4">Not Posted</button>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select @change="toggle_posted(favorite)" v-model="favorite.selected_state" class="form-control form-control-lg">
          <option selected disabled>Choose an action </option>    
          <option v-for="(state, index) in posted_states" :key="index" :value="state.id">{{state.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```